# Communication with "Async" Service in Complex System Architecture

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, microservices, message-queue

In our system, we have around 16 microservices that communicate seamlessly using events through a message broker. These microservices use gRPC as their endpoint communication protocol, with an orchestrator facilitating data consensus as needed. Additionally, we have an API gateway responsible for mapping HTTP requests to gRPC and vice versa.

[image]

The specific challenge I am grappling with arises from a contractual requirement dictating that our entire service infrastructure must route through another service called "Async." This service receives HTTP requests, converts them into AmqpMessages, and dispatches them to a queue. After processing these messages, the results are returned to the Async service in the form of AmqpMessages, which are then delivered to end users.

[image]

The focal point of my inquiry is not the Async service itself, but rather establishing effective communication with it to retrieve messages and delivering processed results back to Async.

The idea I have is to write a Convertor as an external layer and it has the task of converting these messages, but in this case, we have the problem of Middelware, how to implement it.

Comment: Is the "Async" service the only service that you have to interface with, or is it one of many where the others are fine to adhere to your existing contract? Will there probably be many other such non-conforming services like "Async" in the future? Also, what is the business relationship, is this something that will definitely exist for decades or may not be in place in three months? Or somewhere in between? Is your organization flexible enough to pull a hack together and adjust all the services over time or do you need solution up front?

Comment: In fact, in our organization,our product,Also use other products developed by our own organization
And the program that is considered by the organization is that: all the products within the organization are behind the Async system and the end user sees only one URL.
And in the second stage, instead of communicating with each other with HTTP requests, our internal services must communicate through this message broker. This is one of the advantages of  preventing the cost of many HTTP requests and finally, all products under one service can be provided to the end user.

Comment: What is `Convertor` and what problems with what middleware are you expecting? What do you mean by "effective"?

Comment: Also why can't you just call the API gateway? Based on the description seems that for some reason you have 2 layers of API gateways (your actual one and the "Async" one) and based on provided info it seems to be a quite doubtful design decision. Especially from the effectiveness standpoint of view.